# srd-05vdc-sl-c and coil operating time

Tags: relay

I'm using Arduino UNO to control an imatic relay board with 16 relays model [srd-05vdc-sl-c](http://www.circuitbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/SRD-05VDC-SL-C-Datasheet.pdf).
I use all the relays to control some linear actuators and everything is working fine.

My only question is: are the coils used for these relays for **continuous** use? I mean, can I continue to give power to some coils for more than 30 minutes? Or will they be destroyed? 
Should I write a specific Arduino routine to power off all the coils when not used, or can I leave them powered for 30 or more minutes?

I checked the relays and they do not overheat.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave them energized for more than 30 minutes. My 16 year old car with 250,000 km still has the original fuel pump relay. I can't imagine how many hours of continuous use it received over this period of time. The relay in my car is not the same make / model as the relays you are using, so you should check with the manufacture to see if there is a "service lifetime" specification.